# Unable to use pycrypto lib in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

all. I am unable to use pycrypto lib which supposed to come with GAE.
In my app.yaml:

`libraries:
    - name: pycrypto
      version: latest`

In my code:

`from Crypto.Cipher import AES`

This will give me a module not found error. It appears this will happen on any module that is not under C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib

But the package is listed under the GAE supported libraries like webapp2 and others which I do not have such problems.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

There was an issue for a much older version which should be fixed. Issue number 1627.

The issue was fixed by 1.7.4. And I am on 1.9.17.

Anyone ran into this problem as well that could please provide a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Is it works in production? If so, then just install it locally on system level, the same thing happens with lxml.

Comment: It probably will work in production but will be silly for me to do local import then having to change it for production when i need to upload. Anyway, I found a solution which wasn't nice but did work. This goes the same with numpy and others. Will write up my solution later.

Comment: Basically, it had to do with sys.path. You'll have to print this out in your GAE code to figure out where GAE is looking for it. In my case, it was C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\pycrypto-2.6\Crypto. So what I ended up doing was to pip install. Then get it from the python sitepackages folder. Then copy over to the specific path. By the way, the folder name of "Crypto" in site package, can't be the same as the one in your GAE engine. Otherwise when you import it, it might use the one in site-package which will still throw you errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `pip install pycrypto` (or whatever you are normally doing to install new modules) locally and you'll be able to use `pycryto`. I know this contradicts to the regular way you use third-party libs that are supposedly already built-in in GAE but the `pycrypt` module doesn't seem to apply to that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I did that already. It didn't work. The install went into Python lib Site-Package folder. I did find a solution using the hard way. Will write up my solution later when I got time.